# HTTP request failed after listening on multiple ports or enabling SSL Module on my Linux Board

Tags: linux, apache, http, ssl, https

I have one Custom Linux board on which I want to

> run apache web server (httpd) to test HTML

and other web based pages.

I have configured, cross compiled and installed httpd (**2.2.24, 2.4.1, 2.4.4 and 2.4.9 packages) on my Linux PC (Ubuntu 12.04 LTS)** as well as
on my own custom Linux board. Then I have added support of **SSL Module (mod_ssl)** to test HTTP as well as HTTPS request.

Both **HTTP** and **HTTPS** request works fine without any issue on my Linux PC (Ubuntu 12.04 LTS). But when I tried to execute same **HTTP** request
on my Linux Board using httpd (2.4.4 and 2.4.9 with SSL Module Enabled) at that time browser page goes into loading state and can not be came out from that situation.
Also I have seen that **HTTPS** request works fine at that time ( not **HTTP** )

I have also did some debugging task through wire-shark tool and found that connection is established successfully after sending request through **HTTP**
but can not get response of that request. I have also found that response of that **HTTP** request received on wire-shark after closing that **HTTP**
requested page from browser.

Also, I can run **HTTP** and **HTTPS** requests successfully using httpd (2.2.24 and 2.2.27 with SSL Module enabled) on my Linux Board as well but failed to execute same request
using httpd (2.4.X with SSL Module enabled) package.

I have also changed some configurations by creating different virtual host for **HTTP** (Port 80) and **HTTPS** (Port 443) but still failed to
execute that **HTTP** request.

I have also tried to listen on different ports like (Listen 80 and Listen 8000) without SSL module (using httpd 2.4.4. and 2.4.9 ) at that
time **HTTP** request goes into loading state.

Basically all thing works in version 2.2.x but not in 2.4.x.

Does anyone has idea about this issue or help me to solve this type of issue?

Comment: Anything in the error logs? Have you tried to run your Apache server [in the foreground](http://zroger.com/blog/apache-in-the-foreground/) , which might be easier to spot error messages?

Comment: @Bruno  Nothing in error logs.Also tried with running Apachi server in foreground. Also found that it not comes out of `read` function call.

Comment: I have faced similar type of problem while requesting HTTP Page on multiple Listen Directive in my custom linux board. Please configure APR Package with ac_cv_o_nonblock_inherited=no flag which solve HTTP request failed issue on multiple Listen Port.

Comment: @RiteshPrajapati ok i will try.

Comment: @Jayesh Have you tried with that ac_cv_o_nonblock_inherited=no flag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced similar type of problem while requesting HTTP Page on multiple Listen Directive in my custom linux board.

Please configure APR Package with **ac_cv_o_nonblock_inherited=no** flag and configured int with httpd package which will solve HTTP request failed issue on multiple Listen Port.